# Laravel Cashier: Resume a single payment

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

after a successful payment I store the stripe id on a mysql table. With that id I would like to retrieve all the details stored in the stripe database.

So is it possible to resume a single payment by the stripe id?

Thanks

Comment: You said you would like to "resume a single payment" - does that mean you would like to do a one-time charge a 2nd time, or does it mean you would like to resume a subscription plan that you have set up?

Comment: one-time charge and than resume the details for that charge.. no a subscription

Comment: So you want to retrieve all the details stored from the Stripe database after making 1 charge?  You're not trying to make a 2nd charge?

Comment: yes, I don't want to do a second charge. Only resume the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation you need to use:  https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#retrieve_customer

Use the "customer retrieve" Stripe API call to retrieve details about the customer's purchase:

```
 Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('your_stripe_secret_key_here'));
 $customer_object = Customer::retrieve(customers_stripe_id);
```

This will return the following JSON:

```
Stripe\Customer JSON: {
  "id": "cus_7KJZQ8Z6jfSSMl",
  "object": "customer",
  "account_balance": 0,
  "created": 1447172728,
  "currency": "usd",
  "default_source": "card_175evz2eZvKYlo2CKoS2WEDk",
  "delinquent": false,
  "description": "Bingo|www|0c1234567890",
  "discount": null,
  "email": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "shipping": null,
  "sources": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "card_175evz2eZvKYlo2CKoS2WEDk",
        "object": "card",
        "address_city": null,
        "address_country": null,
        "address_line1": null,
        "address_line1_check": null,
        "address_line2": null,
        "address_state": null,
        "address_zip": null,
        "address_zip_check": null,
        "brand": "Visa",
        "country": "US",
        "customer": "cus_7KJZQ8Z6jfSSMl",
        "cvc_check": "pass",
        "dynamic_last4": null,
        "exp_month": 5,
        "exp_year": 2016,
        "funding": "credit",
        "last4": "4242",
        "metadata": {
        },
        "name": null,
        "tokenization_method": null
      }
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 1,
    "url": "/v1/customers/cus_7KJZQ8Z6jfSSMl/sources"
  },
  "subscriptions": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [

    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/customers/cus_7KJZQ8Z6jfSSMl/subscriptions"
  }
}
```

Here is Stripe's version of the API call:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("your_secret_key");
\Stripe\Customer::retrieve("the_customers_id");
```

Make sure to import the \Stripe classes by adding this at the top of your Model or Controller:

```
use Stripe\Customer;
use Stripe\Stripe;
```

if you want to use "Stripe" instead of \Stripe\Stripe and  \Stripe\Customer prefixes)

Comment: but thi is not Laravel Cashier

Comment: It works, and Laravel Cashier doesn't offer a solution here, as far as I can tell.

Comment: If you wanted Laravel Cashier to do it for you, then it would still be doing the exact same thing as above, just wrapping it in a custom function with a different name.

Comment: So it is more complete to use the pure stripe php than Laravel Cashier

Comment: Working with Stripe directly takes away an unnecessary extra layer from Cashier.  The only benefit of Cashier is that it makes it easier to do some common tasks than having to work with the API directly, but as you and I have discovered, Cashier doesn't do everything.  It may not do the above because it is pretty simple.  I spent quite a bit of time a few months ago reading a lot of the Cashier code trying to see how you could do the above, but I never found it, and then I just did it myself directly with the API and it turned out to be not so bad.

Comment: I did find that Cashier makes use of Customer::retrieve in the public function getStripeCustomer in the StripeGateway class.  But the two lines of code above are simpler and most straightforward than trying to hack into that :)

Comment: For instance, in your model, after importing "use Laravel\Cashier\Contracts\Billable as BillableContract;" and "
use Laravel\Cashier\StripeGateway;" and implementing BillableContract  you could use Cashier by doing this:  $billableObject = auth()->user()->setLastFourCardDigits(auth()->user()->last_four);
        $customer_details = (new StripeGateway($billableObject))->getStripeCustomer(auth()->user()->stripe_id); but it's kind of ridiculous.  I'm just using the setLastFourCardDigits method because it returns the $billableObject (there is no simple getter function for the $billableObject)

Comment: It might be worth adding that you can make use of any of Cashier's methods in vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Laravel/Cashier/Billable.php with your User model provided you've set up your User model to implement it, which is pretty complex.  You can get a lot of individual pieces of data from Stripe that way, but you'll have to make a method call to access each individual piece of information.  The way I originally showed you in my answer above gets you all the data in one object right away.

Comment: I have just found an interesting package for laravel: https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/2.0

Comment: Nice!  Cashier and the like tend to add some error-checking features, but really, you can build your own now that you know how to directly interface with Stripe's API.  I like taking out the middleman when possible, as it reduces a whole layer of complexity.